# Discord.py - is it possible to create invite link for all the servers where it is in?

Tags: discord.py

I'd like to get all the invite links from every server that the bot is in but
is it even possible?

Comment: You can get invites with typing `await guild.invites()`

Comment: It sends me "[]" and nothing else...

Comment: You have to get an invite for a channel, do not know if the bot will be able to do that for every guild

Comment: It can do it if the bot has the permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to iterate over [bot.guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20guilds#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds), choose a channel from [guild.text_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20text_channels#discord.Guild.text_channels), and call [.create_invite()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite) on that channel. Here is an example:

```py
invites = []

for guild in bot.guilds:
    for c in guild.text_channels:
        if c.permissions_for(guild.me).create_instant_invite:  # make sure the bot can actually create an invite
            invite = await c.create_invite()
            invites.append(invite)
            break  # stop iterating over guild.text_channels, since you only need one invite per guild
```